# parser in yacc and lex

Tags: c, yacc, lex

so im having some sintax errors my yacc code is
this is project to build a parser and i have already made my keys, reserved words in lex then when 
 in lex im doing the structure that have recursion and rules. 
if i compile in a file .txt a empty file is ok( first rule ) but if i type just {} i have a sintax error .

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h" 
 int yylex(void);
 void yyerror(char *erro);
 char content;


%}
/* Tokens */
%union
{       int num;
        char *string; 
}
%token <num> NUM;
%token <string> STRING;

%token QUOTE COMA DOUBLE_DOTS PAGE PAGE_COUNT ITEMS_PER_PAGE TOOK TIMED_OUT TOTAL RESULTS CONTENTS NAME TYPE PUBLICATION_DATE SHORT_NAME MODEL_TYPE ID LOCATIONS CATEGORIES LEVELS TAGS TAGS REFS LANDING_PAGE COMPANY TRUE_FALSE STRING OBJECT_BEGIN OBJECT_END ARRAY_BEGIN ARRAY_END AGREGATIONS DATE PARAGRAPH_I  PARAGRAPH_E BREAK_E BREAK_I STRONG_I STRONG_E EM EMM
%start DocJSON

%%
/* rules*/
DocJSON:      
      | OBJECT_BEGIN data OBJECT_END   
      ;
data:  
      |    page  page_count  items_per_page  took  timed_out  total results
      ;

page:  PAGE DOUBLE_DOTS NUM COMA
    ;
page_count:  PAGE_COUNT DOUBLE_DOTS NUM COMA
    ;
items_per_page:  ITEMS_PER_PAGE DOUBLE_DOTS NUM COMA
    ;
took: TOOK DOUBLE_DOTS NUM COMA
    ;
timed_out: TIMED_OUT DOUBLE_DOTS TRUE_FALSE COMA
    ;
total: TOTAL DOUBLE_DOTS NUM COMA
    ;
results: RESULTS DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN contents name type publication_date short_name model_type id locations categories levels tags refs company OBJECT_END ARRAY_END COMA
     |
      ;

    contents:  CONTENTS DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING QUOTE COMA 
      |
      ;

    name: NAME DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING QUOTE COMA

      ;
    type: TYPE DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING QUOTE COMA
      |
      ;
    publication_date: PUBLICATION_DATE DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE DATE QUOTE COMA
      |
      ;
    short_name: SHORT_NAME DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING QUOTE COMA
      ;
    model_type: MODEL_TYPE DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING COMA
      ;
    id: ID DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING COMA
      ;

 string: 
      | name
      | name short_name
      | id short_name name
      | landing_page
     ;

    locations: LOCATIONS DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN string OBJECT_END ARRAY_END COMA
      |
      ;
    categories: CATEGORIES DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN string OBJECT_END ARRAY_END COMA
      |
      ;
    levels: LEVELS DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN string OBJECT_END ARRAY_END COMA
      |
      ;
    tags: TAGS DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN string OBJECT_END ARRAY_END COMA
      |
      ;

    refs: REFS DOUBLE_DOTS OBJECT_BEGIN landing_page OBJECT_END COMA
      |
      ;
    company: COMPANY DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN string OBJECT_END COMA
      |      COMPANY DOUBLE_DOTS ARRAY_BEGIN OBJECT_BEGIN string OBJECT_END ARRAY_END COMA agregations
      |
      ;

    landing_page: LANDING_PAGE DOUBLE_DOTS QUOTE STRING QUOTE   
      ;

    agregations: AGREGATIONS DOUBLE_DOTS STRING OBJECT_END
      ;
%%

    void yyerror(char *erro){
            printf("found a error %s \n",erro);

            }

    int main(){
printf("end\n");

         yyparse();
         return(0);
        }
```

i must had miss something , if you have 5 minutes to check, i will be glad

Comment: Please use bison's trace (debugging) facility to show what the parser is doing. Among other things, that will show what tokens it is actually receiving from the lexer; ensure that they are the tokens you expect to see. Tracing is described [here in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Enabling-Traces) but it's really simple: use the `--debug` flag when you invoke bison, and set `yydebug = 1;` before you call `yyparse`.

Comment: I would also suggest that you take a few steps back, simplify the rules, perhaps even to the point of starting over. Then you add one rule at a time, with plenty of testing to make sure it works for all possible correct source you could think of before adding the next rule. But before you even do that, make sure that your *lexer* works as expected. Does it recognize all tokens? Does it return the right token? If you need to, then scale it back as well.